# Putting content below AppBarLayout in a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm very new to Android and I intended to post this to the [Android Developers - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-developers) but they seem to say that newbies need to post to Stack Overflow. So I'm here.

I downloaded the most recent version of ***Android Studio 1.4.1*** yesterday, and I followed the instructions on [Building Your First App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html). I did everything up to [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). It seems these instructions are a bit old i.e. for a previous version of the SDK, because they do not reference `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` though they appear in the code if you follow the steps. Obviously, I did make minor changes in the code to get this app to work, but not completely.

**My Problem:** If you look at the images at the bottom of [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) you will see that both of them have the title **My First App**. In my modifications of the code, I could not get this title on both the images/screens. *(I should mention that I want to use the more recent version of `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinatorLayout`)*

Let's focus on the first screen, the `activity_my.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_my" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" 
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As mentioned at the bottom of [Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html) the `content_my.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there anyway, I can add the `AppBarLayout` to the `activity_my.xml`. I have tried something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/content_my" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" 
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem with this is that the content in `content_my.xml` goes behind the `Toolbar` of `AppBarLayout`  rather than below it. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: This seems to be 2 seperate questions, as to your first one, to get the app title in the toolbar be sure to call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` where `toolbar` is a reference to your Toolbar view. Also, the reason `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout` arent referenced, is because in previous versions of Android Studio, "blank activity" created a completely blank activity. It now creates a simple layout with those 2 elements. The new option is called an "Empty Activity".

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Layouts in a `CoordinatorLayout` need to define a `layout_behavior`. Change your content to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
>

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can have some information in this post http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html in the `CoordinatorLayout, motion, and scrolling` section